# Cartodb search by column

Tags: carto, search

I'm trying to implement a search box that uses my CartoDb data? My current code does not work.

### Html:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/themes/css/cartodb.css" />
<script src="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/cartodb.js"></script>
<div class="panel" style="height:700px">
  <div class="bar">
    <h2 class="beta">My Map</h2>
  </div>
<div id="map"></div>
 <form>
   <input type="Text" name="userInput" id="select-place" class="select-place"> 
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="processFormData();" />
 </form>
</div>
```

### Js:

```js
function processFormData() {
  var input = document.getElementById("select-place").value;
  return input;
}   

function main() {
  cartodb.createVis('map', 'https://testuser.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/123456789/viz.json', {
   title: false,
   description: false,
   tiles_loader: false
  })
  .done(function(vis, layers) {

  var userInput = processFormData();
  var sql = new cartodb.SQL({ user: 'testuser' });
    sql.getBounds("select * from testdb where name like ='%userInput%'").done(function(bounds) {
   map.fitBounds(bounds)
   });

var subLayer = layers[1].getSubLayer(0);
createSelector(subLayer);
 })
 .error(function(err) {
  console.log(err);
 })
 }
 window.onload = main;
```

Answer (score 1):

That code can't work, you need to put the logic on using the SQL API on the function called by the submit button (`processFormData`) and that `createSelector` call is not defined anywhere.